# WSO2 APIM Gateway Environment port to 443 not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm getting this error after I set the [transport.passthru_https.listener.parameters] port to 443

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt8LE.png)

I tried to change it to other ports and it is working, I only encountered this error when changing it to 443.